# IMacros performing action based on EVAL() result?

Tags: imacros

I am new to imacros so i am having a little problem.

I wanted to imacros perform next command based on what result i get from EVAL() in imacros. Like if EVAL() turns to true then visit a link else don't or click a button or not. Is there any way to do it.

For example i am using imacros on firefox.

The code i am running extracts a text from the page and compares it. If it turns to be true, i want it to press submit button else i want to perform all the tasks again

Thanks

Comment: In order to make your question more definite, indicate the following info in the post: (1) what browser you use; (2) what code you want to play if the ‘EVAL’ command returns ‘true’ and what – if ‘false’.

Comment: View some ideas in the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775851/imacros-click-button-or-do-not-click-random-choice
If you want to perform all the tasks again and again, play your macro in loop mode.